# How to show hidden div tag when hover on another div tag using css

Tags: html, css

I have an issue i know it is small but for my necessity i have doubt when i hover on one div i want second div should display and remove cursor again it should hidden how to do this using css

div 2 which will be hidden so when hover on div it should show this div tag and again hover remove it should get hidden using css

```html
<div>
  <a href="javascript:void(0)">
    <div class="show-all-hover-zone" style="height: 212px;">
      <i class="fa fa-chevron-left" style="font-size:25px;color:darkslategrey;position:relative;top:97px;"></i>
    </div>
  </a>

  <div style="background-color:whitesmoke;padding: 3px;height:210px;width:0px;position:absolute;top:164px;display:none;" class="expand-menu1">

  </div>
```

Comment: This code is not well formed. Your nesting is off. Also what you propose is not possible based on the code you have provided.

Comment: You might wanna check the css Selectors [`+`](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_element_pluss.asp) and [`~`](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_gen_sibling.asp)

Answer (score 0):

In your case

`a:hover ~.expand-menu1{
  display: block !important;
}`

But don't use inline, please. It can be much more elegant.
For example:

HTML

```
<a class="hoverOnShow" href="javascript:void(0)">
    <div class="show-all-hover-zone">
        <i class="fa fa-chevron-left" ></i>
    </div>
</a>

<div class="expand-menu1">
</div>
```

CSS

```
.show-all-hover-zone{
  height: 212px;
}
.fa-chevron-left{
  font-size: 25px;
  color:darkslategrey;
  position:relative;
  top: 97px;
}
.expand-menu1{
  background-color:whitesmoke;
  padding: 3px;
  height: 210px;
  width: 0px;
  position:absolute;
  top: 164px;
  display:none;
}
.hoverOnShow:hover ~.expand-menu1{
  display: block;
}
```